# How to create a three-way join table in sequelize without explicitly defining the join table

Tags: sql, node.js, join, sequelize.js

My situation is extremely similar to the one posed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099956/three-way-relationship). My question is whether it is possible to create such a relationship without explicitly defining the join table (e.g. explicitly defining the 'BookmarkTag' table in that example).

Just to be clear, my case is:

File table

Tag table

User table

There is a M:M relationship between File and Tags as an existing Tag can be attached to multiple files. I'd also like to capture which User attached a specific instance of a Tag to a specific file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like you need a `tags` field in `File` table.

Then use a separated coma string to save all tags

```
 update File
 set tags = '<c#>, <sql>, <mysql>'
```

**Tag Table:**

```
 id   tag
 1    <c#>
 2    <sql>
 3    <mysql>
```

The join will be:

```
select F.*, T.*
from File F, Tag T
where exists (SELECT *
              FROM Tag T1
              WHERE CHARINDEX(T1.tag, F.tags)  > 0 )
```

Note: `CHARINDEX` is sql server for find inside string.  You didnt specify any rdbms so I just choose one.